# "Module parse failed: Unexpected token" when added the class field

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

Below TypeScript code (it means that static class fields and other TypeScript features are available) successfully has been built with Webpack:

```
export default class ConfigRepresentative {
  constructor() {
    console.log('ok');
  }
}
```

Fails (same if to remove `private` and `static`):

```
export default class ConfigRepresentative {

  private static ownInstanceHasBeenCreated: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    console.log('ok');
  }
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR in ./TypeScriptSource/index.ts 7:10
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| export default class ConfigRepresentative {
| 
>   private static ownInstanceHasBeenCreated: boolean = false;
| 
|   constructor() {
```

### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {

  entry: './TypeScriptSource/index.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: __dirname,
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },

  target: 'node',
  mode: 'production',
  watch: true,

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  }
};
```

For saving your time on reproducing this problem, I attached the souse files.
[error.zip](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/files/2567961/error.zip)

Answer (score 2):

It is because the project was inside `node_modules` folder. The setting `exclude: /node_modules/` cancels the rule `{test: /\.ts?$/, use: 'ts-loader'}`, but without class property code is pure JavaScript.

(I know that it is bad practice - to develop something inside `node_modules`, however I don't know the other solution for developing dependencies. In this case, single `ConfigRepresentative` is useless if it does not used by other project).